# ¿Todos los graficos de windows se pintan con DirectX y GDI?

Tags: windows

Estoy mirando maneras de representar gráficos para una aplicacion de windows y he visto que DirectX y GDI son las dos maneras que da Microsoft para pintar graficos por lo menos con c++ y me ha surgido la duda de si són las unicas maneras de pintar graficos en windows y si el resto de librerías las usan.

Comment: Es una pregunta amplia. ¿Específicamente en dónde te interesa saber? ¿Aplicaciones del sistema? ¿Cualquier aplicación hechas con Windows Forms?

Comment: @Mateo En windows forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a lo encontrado en la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/graphics-and-multimedia), las APIs gráficas en Windows son:

- OpenGL
- Direct2D
- Direct3D
- GDI
- GDI+
- Win2D
- Vulkan

Aunque solo algunas se usan para dibujar las ventanas de WinForms.

Comment: muchas gracias es justo lo que quería saber